# Haskell - Redefining (hiding) arithmetic operators

Tags: syntax, haskell, functional-programming, notation

I want to redefine several arithmetic operators in Haskell in order to make them more extensible and generic.

E.g.

```
class Mul a b c | a b -> c where
    (*) :: a -> b -> c
```

This seems to work in combination with

```
import Prelude hiding ((*))
```

hiding the standard `*` operator. But of course all usual multiplications have to work as well, so I'd have to define something like

```
instance (Num t) => Mul t t t where
    (*) = ??
```

How can I access the original `*` operator (`Prelude.(*)` doesn't work) here and how do I have to define the instance type such that `1 * 1` doesn't conflict with the *Monomorpism Restriction*?

---

**Edit** -

```
import qualified
```

is a good tip, thanks.

But unfortunately this forced me to bring *all* standard methods into scope explicitly. I just want to have the possibility of redefining certain bindings leaving the rest unchanged.

So is there a combination of both? Something like

```
import Prelude qualified ((*))
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Answering the edited question:

You can do

```
import Prelude hiding ((*))
import qualified Prelude as P
```

to gain access to all Prelude functions except `(*)` in the usual way and to `(*)` via the `P` prefix:

```
x = 5 + 3   -- works
y = 5 P.* 3 -- works
z = 5 * 3   -- complains about * not being in scope
```

Answer (score 4):

The instance

```
instance (Num t) => Mul t t t where
    (*) = ??
```

Will largely defeat the purpose of having defined `Mul t t t` in the first place, without abusing extensions to allow `{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}`.

Unfortunately the 'right' if painful answer is to go through instance by instance and do

```
import Prelude hiding ((*))
import qualified Prelude 

instance Mul Int Int Int where
    (*) = (Prelude.*)

instance Mul Double Double Double where
    (*) = (Prelude.*)


instance Mul Int Double Double where
    ...

instance Mul (Complex Float) (Complex Double) (Complex Double)
    ...
```

Otherwise the way that instance heads get resolved in the compiler (no backtracking is done) will probably make your novel instances cause compilation to blow up when you go to actually use them.

That said, you can at least ease the pain for instances you didn't think of:

```
newtype Other a = Other a

instance Num a => Mul (Other a) (Other a) (Other a) where
    Other a * Other b = Other (a Prelude.* b)
```

This will at least let them just use your newtype wrapper if they don't want to go and define Mul and all of your other classes themselves.

Answer (score 3):

There have been a few attempts to do things like this.

Firstly,

> How can I access the original * operator (Prelude.(*) doesn't work)

You'll need to:

```
import qualified Prelude
```

now you can use e.g. (Prelude.*). This is less aggressive than "LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude" which will also cause local uses of >>= and so on to be rebound to your definitions.

Here are examples of other people's alternative preludes:

- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/prelude-plus -- a simpler prelude (?)
- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude -- an alternative numerical hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

I can answer the first question.  Hiding the (*) operator really hides it, so you can't get at it.  However, you can import Prelude qualified:

```
import qualified Prelude as P

foo = 3 P.* 14 -- == 42
```

I think that that does what you want.